# Cup product of hypercohomologies

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a projective variety and $A$ and $B$ are two vector bundles on $X$. Let $C_{\bullet}$ denote the complex of sheaves

$$
0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow 0
$$

Then we have a cup product in hypercohomology

$$
\mathbb H^i(C_{\bullet})\otimes \mathbb H^j(C_{\bullet})\rightarrow \mathbb H^{i+j}(C_{\bullet}\otimes C_{\bullet})
$$

Is it possible to describe the cup product in terms of the co-cycles? A modern reference will also be helpful.

Comment: This is usually called cross product. Of course you can describe it in terms of cocycles, what other description you know?

Comment: can you describe the cross product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I doubt this counts as  a "modern" reference,  chapter II section 6 of Godement's *Topologie algébrique...* gives the most detailed account that I know for cup products in sheaf cohomology. This includes explicit formulas in terms of Cech cocycles.He doesn't treat products in  hypercohomology, but the formulas are easy to modify:
Given a bounded complex of sheaves $C^\bullet$, choose a good open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$. In your case "good" means affine. One has
$$\mathbb{H}^i(C^\bullet) \cong H^i(\check{C}(\mathcal{U},C^\bullet))$$
where the thing on the right is the cohomology of the total complex of the double complex formed from the Cech complex of $C^\bullet$. You should be able to modify the formulas in Godement to define products in $\check{C}(\mathcal{U},C^\bullet)$. The formulas are a bit messy, otherwise I would write them here.

Comment: understood. thank you